# Prevent Google Translate from translating part of <head> section?

Tags: html, translation, google-translate

Is it possible to tell Google Translate to not translate a section of a site, in this case, part of `<head>` section?

For example:

```
<head>
<title>Post by John Doe</title>
<meta content="Article by John Doe, some brand name here" name="description" />
</head>
```

In this example John Doe and some real brand name could be "translated" to something else, usually it will be wrong translation.

According to https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq#technical `<span class="notranslate"> </span>` around text in html can be used for this.
But, using span class in page title or description, will result by showing that  `<span class="notranslate"> </span>` to users in search engine results as normal page title or description text.

For example if I can wrap part of text from page title or page description in something else like " ", [ ] or ( ), anything else which will look normally.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) is a field which evolves its own sort of common knowledge. This is one of those cases. The generalized way to serve one page to crawlers and another to users is to detect the user agents of relevant crawlers and serve a page which doesn't have the problematic markup, has dynamic content filled-in, etc.

Comment: This question has nothing with "_serve one page to crawlers and another to users_". Same page is made for users and for crawlers.

Comment: This had me thinking otherwise: "But, using span class in page title or description, will result by showing that  <span class="notranslate"> </span> to users in search engine results as normal page title or description text."

Comment: I'm not even sure that putting html tags into titles will NOT be already understood by search engine crawlers, as I don't believe I've ever seen a search result which contained tags like that. However, in the event that such a thing was a concern for you and you still intended to leave the "notranslate" tags in, the only option would be the basic SEO principle I described.

Comment: You can read more [in documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en) about how Google interprets the `<meta name="description">` tag your question is concerned about. It seems a moot point whether the description or title will be translated to users in other languages, since it's likely that they will either be better able to read the translated material compared to being able to read nothing at all, or if they're multilingual, they will be able to de-translate the auto-translated page anyway.

Comment: "_I don't believe I've ever seen a search result which contained tags like that_" that is correct, I never seen that too. That is why I said I can not use that, also I guess it will not be valid html according to W3C. Point of my question: Is there any other way to prevent translation of some part of page title or description, (and to serve that same html page to both users and crawlers)? I thought maybe if I create something like this `<title>Post by (John Doe)</title>` and than to somehow tell to translate engine not to translate text between "(" and ")". But it is not possible.